# Angular RxJS keyboard input emit on enter or debounce time

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I have a search input feature that I would like to be invoked when the user presses enter or when a debounce timeout has elapsed. Basically I want to combine these two paths into a single RxJS observable:

This executes the search on enter:

```html
<input [formControl]="searchInput" (keydown.enter)="search()">
```

This executes the search after a debounce timeout:

```js
searchInput.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => search());
```

This seems like it would be a common requirement, but I haven't been able to figure out how to prevent the redundant emit by `debounceTime`. The best I've been able to do is record the search term and ignore the emit when `debounceTime` fires:

```js
search() {
  if (this.lastUsedSearchTerm != searchInput.value) {
    this.lastUsedSearchTerm = searchInput.value;
    // do search...
  }
}
```

I would like to have a single observable and eliminate the `searchTerm` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try a searching flag and filter the stream on it.

```
searching = false;

searchInput.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap(() => { this.searching = false; }),
  debounceTime(500),
  filter(() => !this.searching)
).subscribe(() => search());

search() {
  this.searching = true;
  // rest of search logic
}
```

Comment: Needing a property outside of the observable pipeline is the complexity I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: How else are you going to get something from outside the stream to effect the stream? If you want a single observable you would end up with a merge of the form control and a subject and internally manage the delay time for the form control and it would be more complicated than a simple searching flag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `(keydown.enter)="search()"` and use only `searchInput.valueChanges`. Also need to refactor the `search` method so that it returns an `Observable` and use it like this:

```
searchInput.valueChanges.pipe(
 debounceTime(500),
 distinctUntilChanged(),
 switchMap((term) => search(term))
).subscribe((response) => {})
```

`switchMap` will allow outgoing requests to be canceled when the value of the search input changes